# Ensembling Technique

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, prediction, ensemble-learning

I want to assign weights to multiple models and make an single ensemble model.
I want to use my outputs as the input to a new machine learning algorithm and the algorithm will learn the correct weights.
but how do I give the output of multiple models as an input to a new ML Algorithm as I am getting output like this

```
preds1=model1.predict_prob(xx)
[[0.28054154 0.35648097 0.32954868 0.03342881]
 [0.20625692 0.30749627 0.37018309 0.11606372]
 [0.28362306 0.33325501 0.34658685 0.03653508]
 ...

 preds2=model2.predict_prob(xx)
[[0.22153498 0.30271243 0.26420254 0.21155006]
 [0.32327647 0.39197589 0.23899729 0.04575035]
 [0.18440374 0.32447016 0.4736297  0.0174964 ]
 ...
```

How to I make a single Dataframe from the output of these 2 or more models ?

the simplest way of doing this is given below but I want to give  the output to a different ML algorithm to learn weights.

```
model = LogisticRegression()
        model.fit(xx_train, yy_train)
        preds1 = model.predict_proba(xx_test)
     

        model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p=2 )
        model.fit(xx_train, yy_train)
        preds2 = model.predict_proba(xx_test)
        
        # Each weight is evaluated by calculating the corresponding score
        for i in range(len(weights)):
         final_inner_preds = np.argmax(preds1*weights[i]+ preds2*(1-weights[i]), axis=1)
       scores_corr_wts[i]+= accuracy_score(yy_test, final_inner_preds)
```

Comment: Ensembling can be done by many ways. The simplest is averaging. In your case, I guess you want to give the biggest weight to the highest class probability amonst your models?  Can you please edit your question and be more specific?

Comment: This is a great topic, but the scope is too big for SO; try datascience.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @azal I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In sklearn you can use the [StackingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html#). This should fit your need.

1. Create a list of the definition of your base model

   `base_models = [('SVC', LinearSVC(C = 1)),('RF',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500))]`
2. Instanciate your Meta-learner

   `meta_model = LogisticRegressionCV()`
3. Instanciate Stacking-Model

   `stacking_model = StackingClassifier(estimators=base_models, final_estimator=meta_model, passthrough=True, cv=3)`
4. Fit and predict

Comment: This is a good solution to my problem but I want to write the code from scratch for "How to I make a single Dataframe from the output of these 2 or more models ?"

Comment: Then just make a now column in your df for every models class propability prediction. Assuming from your predict_proba you got 4 target classes. So introduce 8 more columns in your df and use this for training. Get each column eg for first using df['model1_class1'] = preds1[0:, 0]

Comment: And the 9th column will contain the correct label assigned (out of 4 labels which are - 1,2,3,4).am I right ?

Comment: the correct label assignment is your y vector. The probability matrix is your x. you then use model.fit(x,y) or go through train_test_split beforehand.

Comment: when I will make a dataFrame there will be 8 columns from df[model1_class1] to df[model2_class4] and after training, each column will get a different weight. but from this code  ' final_inner_preds = np.argmax(preds1*weights[i]+ preds2*(1-weights[I])  '  preds1*weights[I] implements that  df[model1_class1]  till df[model1_class4] is multiplied by a  single weight. So will it we conceptually good to 8 different weights from the 8 columns I created in data frame.